# Creating a custom URL in Rails 5 Resource's show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, url-routing

Given the resource Events, I want `/events/1` to navigate to `/events/1/column_name` in the URL bar when entered. Column name is a `t.string  :name` in the Events DB migration. This column_name will need `parameterize` to be called on it before redirecting. Any ideas on how to get this done?

Example:

If you navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/users/4180797 the URL will automatically become https://stackoverflow.com/users/4180797/james-lowrey after loading. Holds true for `4180797/any-other-txt-here`. So "James Lowrey" would be the `name` column, and it would become `james-lowrey` after calling `parameterize` on it.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood your question, could you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks for asking! If you navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/users/4180797 the URL will automatically become https://stackoverflow.com/users/4180797/james-lowrey after loading. Holds true for `4180797/any-other-txt-here`. So "James Lowrey" would be the `name` column, and it would become `james-lowrey` after calling `parameterize` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this was really tricky to figure out, didn't even know I had access to a lot of these variables before.

First edit your `config/routes.rb` to accept `id/other_stuff`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :events
  get "/events/:id/*other" => "events#show" #if any txt is trailing id, also send this route to events#show
end
```

Next modify `event_controller.show` to redirect if the URL is incorrect.

```
  def show
    #redirect if :name is not seen in the URL
    if request.format.html? 
      name_param = @event.name.parameterize
      url = request.original_url
      id_end_indx = url.index(@event.id.to_s) + (@event.id.to_s).length + 1 #+1 for '/' character
      ##all URL txt after id does not match name.parameterize
      if url[id_end_indx..-1] != @event.name.parameterize
        redirect_to "/events/#{@event.id}/#{name_param}"
      end
    end
  end
```

This will result in the exact same behavior as the Stack Overflow examples gave in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Another option will be to use `pushState` with javascript/jquery, for example:

First, add the following `script` in `show.html.erb`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    history.pushState(null, null, "/events/<%= @event.id %>/<%= @event.name.parameterize %>");
  });
</script>
```

This will change the url on load every time, no matter what comes after `/:id`.

Second, modify routes to accept anything after `/:id` (and ignore it):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #...
  get "/events/:id/*other" => "events#show"
end
```

This option has the added benefit of avoiding redirects if any text after `/:id` do not match, it will just get the `id` and replace any other text after that with `@event.name.parameterize` in the url (without any reload).

Comment: Great solution! This avoids redirects and saves a bit of server processing. Wouldn't work if user disables JS though, so there's some trade offs there. Thanks for the answer!